# How to delete Search Folders

Tags: vba, email, outlook

Is it possible to delete Search Folders in Outlook using VBA?

I'm trying to figure out, but I don't know how to do it.

My goal is to make a search folder as a temporary storage of my mails and delete it after accessing the emails inside the search folder. I already have the code for creating search folder. But what I want to do is delete the search folder.

I found a code in slipstick.com but my knowledge is not enough to understand the whole process of the program:

http://www.slipstick.com/developer/create-an-outlook-search-folder-using-vba/

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Delete](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff863914.aspx) method of the Folder class.